# unable to form structure and filter out the tab when tab is empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to form the structure like `expectedOutput` by iterating tabs data and filter tabs, when tab is empty, no need have corresponding tab when the array is empty

```js
let tabs = {
  'tab1': [{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'jim'},
           {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim'}],
  'tab2': [{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'jim'},
           {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim'}],
  'tab3': []
}


let expectedOutput = {
  'tab1': [{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'jim'},
           {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim'}],
  'tab2': [{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'jim'},
           {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim'}],
}
let newTabs = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(tabs).map(([tab, data]) => {
    if (tabs[tab] && tabs[tab].length > 0)
      data = data.map(d => ({ ...d }));
    return [tab, data];
  })
);
console.log("original", tabs);
console.log("new", newTabs);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `.map()`,  you're usually do a one-to-one mapping. As a result, using `.map()` to remove entries from the array returned by `Object.entries()` isn't where you want to put this logic. Instead, you can [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) your entries array using:

```
.filter(([,data]) => data.length)
```

Above, the `filter()` method works on an array of entries which looks like:

```
[[key, value], [key2, value2], ... ]
```

As a result, when you use `.filter()` on the above array, the callback passed into filter is given each of the above inner key-value pair arrays. The first time it is called, the callback is given the first inner array of `[key, value]`. This array can be [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) using `[,data]`. This will grab the second value from the `[key, value]` array. In this case, it will grab `value` and ignore the key. The above `filter` can be re-written to be:

```
.filter((entryArr) => entryArr[1].length > 0)
```

The above line of code is the same as the filter method being used.

When the length of `data` (i.e an array value in your object) is 0, it will be removed from the resulting array (as 0 is a falsy value), otherwise, if `data` does have a length greater than 0, then it will be kept in the resulting array.

See example below:

```js
const tabs = {'tab1': [{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'jim'}, {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim'}], 'tab2':[{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'jim'}, {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim'}], 'tab3':[]};

const newTabs = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(tabs).filter(([,data]) => data.length).map(([tab,data]) => [
    tab,
    data.map(d => ({...d}))
  ])
);
console.log("original",tabs);
console.log("new",newTabs);
```

Comment: @chidananda yes. As we want to remove empty arrays, we want to return false when `data` has a length of 0, and true when it has a length greater than zero. Doing `data.length` will return `0` when the array is empty. Since the callback for filter expects a boolean (true/false) to be returned, the value `0` will be converted into a boolean automatically. Since zero is considered falsy, so it gets converted to `false`. When another number such as 1 is returned, it will get converted into `true` as all other numbers except 0 are considered truthy.

Comment: @chidananda you can read more about [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) and [truhy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) values here.

Answer (score 2):

Could also try:

```js
const tabs = {
  'tab1': [{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'jim'},
           {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim'}],
  'tab2': [{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'jim'},
           {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim'}],
  'tab3': []
}

const newTabs = {}
Object.keys(tabs).forEach(a => tabs[a].length ? newTabs[a] = tabs[a] : '')

console.log(newTabs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```js
let tabs = {
  'tab1': [{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'jim'},
           {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim'}],
  'tab2': [{id:'1',mnemonic:'first',value:'jim'},
           {id:'2',mnemonic:'second',value:'kim'}],
  'tab3': []
}

let newTabs = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(tabs).filter(([tab, data]) => data.length > 0)
)

console.log("new", newTabs);
```